# Python: adding namespaces in lxml

Tags: python, lxml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to specify a namespace using *lxml* similar to this example (taken from [here](http://www.maconstateit.net/tutorials/XML/XML03/xml03-01.htm)):

```xml
<TreeInventory xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Trees.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
</TreeInventory>
```

I'm not sure how to add the Schema instance to use and also the Schema location.
The [documentation](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html#namespaces) got me started, by doing something like:

```py
>>> NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
>>> TREE = '{%s}' % NS
>>> NSMAP = {None: NS}
>>> tree = etree.Element(TREE + 'TreeInventory', nsmap=NSMAP)
>>> etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)
'<TreeInventory xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>\n'
```

I'm not sure how to specify it an instance though, and then also specify a location.  It seems like this can be done with the `nsmap` keyword-arg in `etree.Element`, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In some more steps, for clarity:

```
>>> NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
```

As far as I can see, it is the attribute `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` that you want namespaced, not the `TreeInventory` element. So:

```
>>> location_attribute = '{%s}noNamespaceSchemaLocation' % NS    # f-string doesn't work in this case
>>> elem = etree.Element('TreeInventory', attrib={location_attribute: 'Trees.xsd'})
>>> etree.tostring(elem, pretty_print=True)
'<TreeInventory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Trees.xsd"/>\n'
```

This looks like what you wanted...
You could of course also create the element first, without attributes, and then set the attribute, like this:

```
>>> elem = etree.Element('TreeInventory')
>>> elem.set(location_attribute, 'Trees.xsd')
```

As for the `nsmap` parameter: I believe it is only used to define which prefixes to use on serialization. In this case, it is not needed, because lxml knows the commonly used prefix for the namespace in question is "xsi". If it were not some well-known namespace, you would probably see prefixes like "ns0", "ns1" etc..., unless you specified which prefix you preferred. (remember: the prefix is not supposed to matter)

Comment: Just small correction: Should be noNamespaceSchemaLocation, no noNameSpaceSchemaLocation.

Comment: f-strings **do** work: `f'{{{NS}}}noNamespaceSchemaLocation'`